# Adding some CSS using wp_footer hook doesn't work

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

To make the WooCommerce product image "display" the right way, I'm using CSS by usig the `wp_footer` hook. This way, the product thumbnail is displayed correctly on the checkout with `margin`, etc.

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ls_product_image_css_checkout', 900 );
function ls_product_image_css_checkout() {

    // run only on checkout
    if ( is_checkout() ) { ?>

        <style>
        .product-item-thumbnail{ float:left; padding-right:20px; }
        .product-item-thumbnail img{ margin:0!important; }
        </style>

    <?php
    }
}
```

Now, here is my REAL problem and YES, I have tried various CSS solutions since the product removal has a `<a class=""` and yet, no matter what I do - the `X` for removing the product from checkout is displayed on the right of the thumbnail, directly next to the `Product Name`.

I need the `X` for removal to be placed on the `LEFT` of the `thumbnail`.

**This is the code I am using:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'ls_product_removal_on_the_left_of_product_image_on_checkout', 20, 3 );
function ls_product_removal_on_the_left_of_product_image_on_checkout( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    // only on checkout, of course
    if ( is_checkout() ) {

    // get cart
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

        // loop through cart
        foreach ( $cart as $cart_key => $cart_value ) {

            if ( $cart_key == $cart_item_key ) {

                $product_id = $cart_item[ 'product_id' ];
                $_product = $cart_item[ 'data' ];

                // this is part of what I cannot figure out
                $remove_product = sprintf(
                '<a class="rpfc" href="%s" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">&#10005;</a>',
                esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_key)), __( 'Delete this product from my order', 'woocommerce' ),
                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku()),
                esc_attr( $cart_item_key ));
            }
        }

        // get product data
        $product = $cart_item[ 'data' ];

        // display the iamge on checkout, 40*40 px
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image( array( 40, 40 ) );

        // the HTML
        $image_html = '<div class="product-item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>';

        // get the product name and link it. If clicked, re-directed to the product page
        $product_name_link = '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product_name . '</a>';

        // the removal of the product BEFORE the image
        // REMOVAL (on the left of the image) IMAGE PRODUCT NAME
        $product_name = $remove_product . $image_html . $product_name_link;
    }

    return $product_name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For styles (CSS) never use the footer as the CSS will never be applied, always use the head. So you need to replace `'wp_footer'` hook by `'wp_head'` instead. It should solve the problem.

The hook `'wp_footer'` is used sometimes to add some JavaScript (jQuery) code.

---

To run this code only in checkout page, replace:

```
if ( is_checkout() ) {
```

with:

```
if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
```

This way the code will be only effective in checkout page, but not in "order received" *(thankyou)* and not in "Order pay" pages.

---

If some CSS rules doesn't work, you may need (or try) to:

- increase the hook priority like:

  ```
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'ls_product_image_css_checkout', 999999 );
  ```
- add `!important` on each rule that doesn't work, like: `float:none !important;`

Comment: Thank you for a very QUICK response, but what do you mean? I changed the hook for the how the thumbnail should be aligned on the checkout from 'wp_footer' into 'wp_head' - but that changed nothing. The removal link (the X) is still on the RIGHT hand side of the thumbnail and right next to the product name. Any further ideas?

Comment: So your css rules are not correct (meaning the selector), or you need to add `!important`at the end of each rule something like: `padding-right:20px !important;`

Comment: Ah, I did it! Thank you! My gosh... it really was that simple :) Thank you.